# How to repeat without using "for" or "while" or "repeat" functions?

Tags: matlab

Is there a function that can repeat a segment of code for a given number of times?

for example:

```
t= 0; 
while (t< 10) 
  if x==2 
    x=1 
  else 
    x=3; 
  end 
end
```

How can i rewrite this function using another function ?

Comment: Can you give us some context about what you are trying to do?

Comment: for example:
  t= 0;
  while (t< 10)
    if x==2
       x=1
    else x=3;
  end

How can i rewrite this function using another function ?

Answer (score 4):

A recursive function can do this for you (assuming you can't use: for,while,repeat).

http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/recursion.html

Answer (score 2):

Or, if the code executed in one iteration is **independent** on the results of other iterations, you can use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) or [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html).

For instance

```
 fun = @(x) disp(['hello ' , num2str(x)]);
 arrayfun(fun,1:5);
```

returns

```
 hello 1
 hello 2
 hello 3
 hello 4
 hello 5
```

---

*Personally* I do like these constructs because I find them very *expressive* just as `std::for_each` in C++.

Nonetheless, they have proven to be slower than their naive-loop counterparts which get *JITed* away by Matlab (there are several Q/A about this issue here on SO).

Comment: `arrayfun` and `cellfun` are essentially loops with extra overhead... I believe it is recursion the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab automatically 'repeats' the code for you if you put it in a vector format:

```
x_vector = round(2*rand(10,1)) %Your x input
idx = (x_vector==2)
x_vector(idx) = 1;
x_vector(~idx) = 3;
```